# Python 3.3.2 invalid syntax error

Tags: python

```
bif="Sadness.jpg"

mif="circles.png"

import pygame,sys

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)

background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()

mouse_c=pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()

x,y=0,0

movex, movey = 0,0

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:

            pygame.quit()

            sys.exit()


            if  event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==K_LEFT:
                    movex=-1
                elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                    movex=+1
                elif event.key==K_UP:
                    movey=-1
                elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                    movey=+1
            if event.type == K_UP:
                  if event.key==K_LEFT:
                    movex=0
                  elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                    movex=0
                  elif event.key==K_UP:
                    movey=0
                  elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                    movey=0

            x+=movex
            y+=movey

            screen.blit(background, (0,0))
            screen.blit((mouse_c,(x,y))


            pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Could you please post the full traceback?

Comment: @jh314: What if that incorrect indentation you just fixed **was the error**?

Comment: Maybe.  You just added 4 spaces to every line, right?

Comment: Thank you @Haidro ,the parentheses was the problem...but then during execution , the output screen is blank(black)..the program is supposed to show the background "sadness" having the "circle" at one of the corners,where the circle can be moved using the arrowkeys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`screen.blit((mouse_c,(x,y))`

You seem to have an extra parenthesis `(`. This'll make python think you are continuing the code on the next line, but you aren't intentionally doing so, and thus you are creating some weird syntax (hence the SyntaxError). This is also why your traceback may not actually point to the line with the extra parenthesis, but the one below it.

Comment: Thank you @Haidro ,the parentheses was the problem...but then during execution , the output screen is blank(black)..the program is supposed to show the background "sadness" having the "circle" at one of the corners,where the circle can be moved using the arrowkeys.

Answer (score 1):

```
screen.blit((mouse_c,(x,y))
```

has an opening parenthesis too many (or is missing a closing parenthesis).